# Difference between the graded symmetric algebra and the exterior algebra

Tags: exterior-algebra, graded-algebras, superalgebra, symmetric-algebra

The graded symmetric algebra is the tensor algebra modulo the supercommutator $xy-(-1)^{|x||y|}yx$ where $|x|$ is the grade of $x$.

The Wikipedia article says that this generalizes both the symmetric and exterior algebras, but I don’t see how it generalizes either of them.

What is the connection here?

Answer (score 0):

The [WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded-symmetric_algebra) explains in the last two sentences how symmetric and exterior algebras are special cases of the graded-symmetric algebra. If $M$ is an ungraded module over an ungraded ring, then:

- $M\oplus 0$ is a purely even supermodule, and its graded-symmetric algebra is just the usual symmetric algebra, concentrated in even degree as a superalgebra ($SM\oplus 0$).
- $0\oplus M$ is a purely odd supermodule, and its graded-symmetric algebra is just the usual exterior algebra, with its usual $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading as a superalgebra ($\Lambda^{\rm even}\oplus\Lambda^{\rm odd}$).